# Question on three algebraic expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, fractions

Assume that $a < b$ , and both are natural numbers (like 2 or 4).

1. Is $a/b$ * $a/b$ more, less or equal to $a/b$ ?
2. Is $a/b$ / $a/b$ more, less or equal to $a/b$ ?
3. Is $ab/a$ - $ab/b$ more, less, or equal to $a/b$ ?

What I'm looking for is advanced answers (well, I'm 15 so maybe not extreme answers), that can showcase that I know if it's more, less or equal to $a/b$.

Here are my thoughts;

1. Let a = 2, b = 4.

   $2/4$ * $2/4$ = $4/16$ , $4/16$ is not equal to $8/16$. Which means that $a^2/b^2$ is not equal to $a/b$, it's lower than it. (Can anyone please show me how I can explain this further ? I know that I can say that because $a < b$, the fraction ($a/b$) < $1$ ).
2. $2/4$  / $2/4$  = $1$ , $2/4 < 1$, which means that $a/b$ / $a/b$ is not equal to $a/b$, it's more than it. (Same thing here, how do I advance this answer by showcasing it more by fractions? I know that I can write that $a/b$ / $a/b$ = $a*b$ / $a*b$ = 1. But further advancement would be great!).
3. $8/2$ - $8/4$ = $4 - 2$ = $2$, Which means that it's more than $a/b$. (Could anyone help me here, should I multiply the fractions which a and then b -- if that works could anyone here show it?).

I'm really thankful for any answers that could advance my solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $$a<b$$
   $$\frac ab<1$$
   $$\frac{a^2}{b^2}<\frac ab$$
2. As $\frac ab<1$ and $\frac{\frac ab}{\frac ab}=1$, $\frac ab<\frac{\frac ab}{\frac ab}$
3. $$\frac{ab}a-\frac{ab}b=\frac{ab^2-a^2b}{ab}=\frac{ab(b-a)}{ab}=b-a$$

As b and a are natural nos. with $a<b$, $$b-a>=1>\frac ab$$
$$\frac{ab}a-\frac{ab}b>\frac ab$$

Just remember that most rules for equation solving applying to inequalities as well, so you can transpose and add/delete terms in the same manner.

P.S. I'm only 13 and I'm answering your question.

Comment: I'll read your answer after dinner but I loved your last comment :], You see, in my country (specifically my school) -- this kind of math is considered hard :] (Well it's hard to always prove expressions and so on).

Comment: a) Are you a boy?      b) Are you an Indian by any chance, because it's night for me too.      c) You said you find this kind of maths hard. What do you really find easy then?

Comment: d) You could accept answers rather than up-voting them. Both you and the answerer earn more reputation.

Comment: Oh trust me I know how to do it; I just finished dinner and had to do a short errand before checking your answer. Anyway though, I'm really thankful for your answer as I truly understand how to prove the questions now. Thank you! EDIT: Yes I'm a boy, and no I'm not indian :) c) I find probability really easy (I had 100% right on my last math test on probability), and the rest I find somewhat challenging I guess..